# XML mapper... XE2

Tags: xml, web-services, delphi, soap, delphi-xe2

I have an xml from a webservice that I want to store in a ClientDataSet.

When using the XML mapper no data is shown in the grid (when using the
"Create and Test Transformation"), so I'm not able to use the
transformation file...

Here is some of the response XML from the C# Webservice (one row of data)...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap:Body>
<AllResponse xmlns="http://some.url.com/">
<AllResult>
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" msdata:IsDataSet="true" name="NewDataSet">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
<xs:element name="Table">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Id" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="UserName" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Name" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="PhoneInt" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="CostCentre" minOccurs="0" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="GroupRoleNameDK" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="GroupRoleNameUK" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Email" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Url" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="PhoneAlt" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="PhoneMobile" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Fax" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="EducationNameDK" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="EducationNameUK" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Location" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="PhoneNote" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Personid" minOccurs="0" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="GroupId" minOccurs="0" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="GroupNameDK" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="GroupNameUK" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<Id>P-4</Id>
<UserName>auser</UserName>
<Name>Somename</Name>
<PhoneInt>aPhone</PhoneInt>
<CostCentre>0</CostCentre>
<GroupRoleNameDK>WebService</GroupRoleNameDK>
<GroupRoleNameUK>WebService</GroupRoleNameUK>
<Email>aname@acompany.com</Email>
<Url>http://www.embarcadero.com</Url>
<PhoneMobile>12345678</PhoneMobile>
<Fax>87654321</Fax>
<Personid>4</Personid>
<GroupId>618</GroupId>
<GroupNameDK>Danish Group</GroupNameDK>
<GroupNameUK>GroupName</GroupNameUK>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</AllResult>
</AllResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The schema seems to be well defined, so I'm a bit puzzled, why it
doesn't work.
I have noticed that some of the fields have <Field/> instead of
<Field></Field> when the field is empty - doesn't know if that matters...

Any idea how I get along?

-Kurt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I needed to change the .XTR file very first line
See Deepak's article http://www.agnisoft.com/white_papers/soap1.asp

Quote:

> The reason for this is that Delphi's XML Transform provider  does not
>   like the "soap:" in the first element of the "from" attribute  (and
>   all such namespaces in the "source"). That might get fixed in some 
>   update pack, so this point might not apply

This is not fixed in Delphi XE2...

-Kurt

Answer (score 0):

The response contains two parts, a XML schema definition just like in an XSD document, and a data part.

If the XML data binding wizard in XE2 does not like this format, I would

- extract the schema part (once) and create an XSD from it which can be processed by the wizard
- extract the data part from the XML document (for every response) and feed it to the transformation component

Comment: @Kurt To extract the data part, I would read the XML into a IXmlDocument. Then load the Table element (with its subnodes) into a IXmlNode, and add it to a second (empty) IXmlDocument.